# Modifying structure of CMS generated markup for Semantic UI grid

Tags: css-selectors, content-management-system, semantic-ui, generated-code

Is there a way to add a div in between the row and the column divs without reengineering the whole grid styles? The CMS I'm trying to integrate SUI with inserts an unwanted div that I can't get rid of. The new structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="UNWANTED DIV">
      <div class="column">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that SUI expects the next div after to row to be a div with class column and I can't do that unfortunately. Do I have to modify the semantic grid CSS to account for this or is there some magic fix?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement to merge the `outerHTML` and `innerHTML` of the unwanted div. For example:

```js
var foo = document.querySelector(".row > div");
if(foo.className === "UNWANTED DIV")
  {
  foo.outerHTML = foo.innerHTML;
  }

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```css
.row > .column { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="UNWANTED DIV">
      <div class="column">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**References**

- [MutationObservers: innerHTML, outerHTML mutations](https://www.w3c-test.org/dom/nodes/MutationObserver-inner-outer.html)
- [The Web Platform Tests Project: Test Suites for Web Platform Specifications](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests)
- [innerHTML and outerHTML to Get and Replace HTML content](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/innerhtml-outerhtml-get-replace-html-content_t)